# Как нарисовать прямоугольник по центру картинки?

Tags: c#

Хочу пропорционально размерам картинки где то в районе его центра нарисовать красный прямоугольник. Но к сожалению картинка смещается влево. Что не так?

```
var recHeight = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * 0.23);
var recWidth = Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * 0.33);

var posH = Convert.ToInt32((img.Height - recHeight) / 2);
var posW = Convert.ToInt32((img.Width - recWidth) / 2);

Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(posH, posW, recWidth, recHeight);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rec.Width, rec.Height);
using (Graphics gph = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        gph.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала `Х`, потом `Y`:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(posW, posH, recWidth, recHeight);
```

Эта строчка не нужна:

```
// Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rec.Width, rec.Height);
```